# OpenGL Won't Close on Mouse Click (mouseFunc) - glutKeyboardFunc is fine?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have my program configured to close when I press the 'q' key. It was simple enough to orchestrate after reading the glutKeyboard prototype, so I thought I would also add the option to close with the right mouse button. However, no matter what I do, I can't get this to work. I'm curious if there is some subtle difference between mouseFunc and keyboardFunc that I'm missing? Here is my code:

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
//#include <assert.h>

void init (void)
{

glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); /* Set background to yellow */
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}

void display(void)
{

glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

glVertex2d (0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2d (1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2d (0.5, 0.866);

glEnd();

glFlush (); //Display immediately

}

void keyEscape( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
switch ( key )
{
case 113: // 'Q' key for escape
  int windowID = glutCreateWindow ("triangle");
  glutDestroyWindow (windowID);
  exit (0);
  break;
}

glutPostRedisplay();

}

void mouseEscape( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
{

    int windowID = glutCreateWindow ("triangle");
    glutDestroyWindow (windowID);
    exit (0);

    glutPostRedisplay();

}

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize (250, 250);
glutInitWindowPosition ((glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)-250)/2, (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT)-250)/2);
glutCreateWindow ("triangle");
init ();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyEscape);
glutMouseFunc(mouseEscape);
glutMainLoop();

return 0;

}
```

I parsed out a few more keyboard shortcuts (such as z for zooming) that all work similarly, hence my use of a switch statement as opposed to an if, but that is the only real difference I can see, and attempting to use a switch case has not worked for me either. I've also tried moving the redisplay command outside the if, to no avail. Any idea why mouse closing won't cooperate, but key closing will?

Comment: Some ideas: (1) Do you have a menu attached to that button (may be you left that code out)? (2) Is the mouse pointer inside the window area when you press? (3) Does it work with the left button? (4) In debugging, is the if statement really executed?

Comment: Is `glutPostRedisplay();` supposed to be at the scope of your `if` condition in `mouseEscape (...)`? It is triggered unconditionally in `keyEscape (...)`, which I find interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was somehow building against an old .exe that wouldn't updated even with a 'Clean Project' operation. I changed projects and now all is fine... Thanks for the assistance all the same!